# how to set auto break option in android textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` in my android app with **long text** in it.

> The problem is the TextView will not break automatically to new line.

Here is my code for that `TextView`

```
TextView txt = new TextView(this);

txt.setText("im not a superman and i have many friends not having any powers");
txt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 13);
txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);          
txt.setPadding(dp(10), dp(10), dp(20), 0);
txt.setSingleLine(false);
txt.setLines(2);
txt.setMaxLines(4);
txt.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving your TextView all the space it wants with "WRAP_CONTENT". Make sure your parent view has a specific width and try changing

```
txt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

to

```
txt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Not working how? Not compiling or don't give the behavior you were expecting? Since I'm confident that the code will compile, I suspect that you still don't get your string on multiple rows. In that case you will need to make sure the width of the parent view has a specific width (i.e. that it is not "WRAP_CONTENT") or set a specific width on your tablerow (e.g. set width to "20dp" instead of "MATCH_PARENT")